# Non-normalized quaternion derivative

Tags: rotations, quaternions

I know that for normalized quaternion, $\hat{q}$, the derivative is given by $$\frac{d\hat{q}}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}\hat{q}\cdot \omega$$ where $\cdot$ denotes the quaternion multiplication.

I want to calculate the time derivative of a non-normalized quaternion $q$.

I tried to calculate the derivative by using the chain rule,  $$\dot{q}=\left|q\right|\dot{\hat{q}}+\hat{q}\frac{d\left|q\right|}{dt}$$  and I got a very complicated term. I wonder if I am having a wrong approach and if there is a known formula?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that $q=\vert q \vert \hat q$, therefore the $\vert q\vert$ in your formula are inverted.

Comment: Thanks,  I accidentally write the derivative of $\hat{q}$, I changed it.

Comment: Isn't the derivative of the normalized quaternion only defined that way because it can represent a 3D rotation? A non-normalized quaternion therefore doesn't have a direct relation with $\omega$ and so $\dot{q}$ would not be defined.

Comment: From what I understood, only normalized quaternion can represent a 3D rotation. However, since I use the quaternion in extended Kalman filter simulation I must normalize the quaternion for each iteration.  The forced normalization can cause numerical errors in the estimation of the covariance matrix (losing positive semidefenitness) and the Kalman filter might diverge.  For this reason, I wanted to propagate the quaternion as non-normalized vector and normalized it only when I need to find the object orientation.